# baseQueue is undefined when trying to fetch data using react-query

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

I'm not able to fetch data from react query in one of my components but the exact same fetch funtion and key worked somewhere else just fine,

I'm getting this strange error saying

> baseQueue is undefined

The error is thrown by useQuery() hook so I'm unable to understand what's happening.

```js
const dataSourceColorMap = {
  cms: "blue",
  epic: "red",
  athena: "purple",
};
const GiveOrgAuth = () => {
  const {
    data: profile,
    isLoading,
    isError,
  } = useQuery("profile", fetchProfile);
  return (
    <Page title="Give Auth to your org">
      <Grid>
        <Grid.Col span={4}>
          <ConnectPayers />
        </Grid.Col>
        <Grid.Col span={4}>
          <ConnectEMRs />
        </Grid.Col>
        <Grid.Col span={4}>
          <DevFetch />
        </Grid.Col>
      </Grid>
      <Paper mt="md">
        <Title order={4}>Currently Connected Sources</Title>
        {!isLoading && !isError ? (
          profile.dataSources.map((source) => (
            <Badge color={dataSourceColorMap[source]}>{source}</Badge>
          ))
        ) : (
          <></>
        )}
      </Paper>
    </Page>
  );
};
```

Here's the fetchProfile function

````js
export const fetchProfile = async () => {
  const res = await axios.get("/api/user/profile");
  return res.data;
};```
````

I tried to render one of they keys in profile object but it's working only half the time

Answer (score 0):

I found out a solution, it's giving me the error when I don't add keys while iterating over the profile.dataSources array which I don't fully understand like yeah react uses keys to identify if a component is changed or not, but I'm still curious why react-query was giving that error